# Subnet plan with efficient use of a range of ip adresses

Tags: networking, ip, cisco, subnet

Good morning, so basically I am working with Packet Tracer atm and have 3 subnet plans assigned(management(104users), staff(43 users) and admin(35 users)). I have an ip address range of:38.191.0.0 and subnet mask of 255.255.255.0. I want to produce that subnet plan but with the most efficient use of the ip address range provided above. Could anyone give me a brief idea of how to transform that range to the most efficient use of the IP addresses? Thank you very much. The diagram looks as follows:

[image: packet tracer diagram]

Comment: you're showing a switch, but apparently want subnets.  Are you using VLANs and L3 switching to separate the users?  ps. this is off-topic for stackoverflow.com

Comment: Yes that is it, I'm implementing VLAN's for each of the switches alog with inter-VLAN routing (router on a stick method). I didn't know it was off topic my apologies

Comment: Given the three groups you have, the only practical splits are a /25 for management, and a /26 for each of users and admin.

Comment: Hum, makes sense indeed. I'll have a thorough look at it but thank you ver much for answering this off topic subject

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. It is off topic here and should be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answering in anticipation of this getting moved to a different SE site)

Given the size of your three groups (104, 43, 35) the only reasonable split is to allocate each of them to the next higher power of two, specifically (128, 64, 64) making that a /25 and two /26 blocks with nothing left over.

Note that this gives you 22 spare addresses in the first block, 19 in the second and 27 in the last.

p.s. is 38.191.0.0/24 really your netblock?

Comment: Don't answer off topic questions.

Comment: @AndrewMedico  so just vote to close and help get it moved - no need to down vote stuff that'll be correct once it's on the right site.

Comment: If you want to answer it, wait until it's moved. Answering off-topic questions only encourages people to keep posting them. It is harmful to the site.

Comment: yes the instructions from the exercise i'm working on give that range of ip's

Comment: hey andrew i honestly didn't know and her/his answer does not encourage me to post other off topic questions, she/he was explicit and I won't do it again.

Comment: @JGuerra Oh look, you *did* do it again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37463414/dividing-a-given-network-in-4-subnets